# Wordpress functions.php shortcode is not working

Tags: shortcode

I have new WordPress (5.0.2) install with the code added to the end of functions.php file:

```
function testsc(){
    return "It is working!";
}

function testsc2(){
    return "It is working!";
}

add_shortcode('testshortcode', testsc);
add_shortcode('testshortcode2', 'testsc2');
```

With Debug Objects plugin installed i can see that short codes are added:

```
Shortcode: testshortcode Function: testsc
Shortcode: testshortcode2 Function: testsc2
```

But when i put testshortcode or testshortcode2 in a page it is treated as text.

I use default theme: Twenty Sixteen.

Comment: Try `'testSC'` instead of `testSC` (unquoted), when in the `add_shortcode()` call.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Did you try with the Shortcode or Code block in the new editor? And you're referring to the theme's `functions.php` file, right? Try disabling all or certain plugins on your site.

Comment: I used Shortcode block from new editor. Other blocks generate error during saving. Yes. I am refering to the theme's functions.php. I don't have active any plugin besides Debug Objects.

Comment: Try using lowercases.. `testshortcode`.

Comment: Your shortcode also needs to `return` its contents.

Comment: @hal, I mean, `add_shortcode('testshortcode', 'testSC');` and `[testshortcode]` - lowercase both when registering and using the shortcode. And Milo is right - a shortcode should return an output (and not echo it) so that you'd see something (in the correct place/position) when the shortcode is used - `[testshortcode]`.

Comment: the lack of quotes in the code is definitely a problem, even if it doesn't get it working, it does need to be fixed. As for the shortcode itself, `[testshortcode]` on a post would be how you would test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked.

To ensure that, all following conditions must be met:

- declarations must be in lowercase
- do not use echo but return the content
- square brackets are required even in the shortcode block.

Comment: You should paste your final solution and accept the answer.

Comment: "square brackets are required even in the shortcode block" means to type `[testshortcode]` into the shortcode block in the editor instead of `testshortcode` for my fellow newbs.